# perimeter of periodic binary matrix (in matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a periodic binary matrix which includes a block of ones. I need to find the boundary between zeros and ones in the matrix. Here is an example:

```
A=[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1;
   0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0;
   0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0;
   0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0;
   0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0;
   0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0;
   0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0;
   0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0;
   0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

If the matrix was not periodic, I could use

```
perim=bwperim(A);
```

to find the perimeter. But this does not work perfectly for periodic matrices. I appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem.

EDIT:
a periodic matrix is a matrix that its boundary elements are connected to the boundary elements on the other side of the matrix.

Comment: @Giogre Just editted. See here for more information on periodic matrices: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/125143-connected-components-for-periodic-image

Comment: I think it's clear from the above link. @Giogre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the image on each side with the column/row that it's connected to. For example, the left edge will be padded with the rightmost column. Then use `bwperim`, and trim one row/column from each side of the result.

```
A = [0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1;
     0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0;
     0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0;
     0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0;
     0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0;
     0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0;
     0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0;
     0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0;
     0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0];

padded_A = [0        A(end,:) 0;
            A(:,end) A        A(:,1);
            0        A(1,:)   0];

padded_perim = bwperim(padded_A);
perim = padded_perim(2:end-1,2:end-1);
```

Result:

```
perim =
  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0
  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks. A remaining point is that, I need an algorithm that works for any matrix A with any size. The matrix A in the question was just an example.

Comment: I wrote my answer so that it would work for any size. There is nothing in there that places any restrictions on the size other than `A` must not be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) and [`padarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to find the perimeter:

`4-connected:`

```
perim = A & conv2(padarray(A, [1 1], 'circular'), [0 1 0;1 0 1;0 1 0], 'valid') < 4;
```

`8-connected:`

```
perim = A & conv2(padarray(A, [1 1], 'circular'), [1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1], 'valid') < 8;
```

Using the [definition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html) of the perimeter:

> A pixel is part of the perimeter if it is nonzero and it is connected to at least one zero-valued pixel.

Use `A & ...` to ensure that the pixel is nonzero. The boundary pixels are replicated using `padarray` with option `'circular'`. The padded array is convolved with the connectivity mask. use `conv2` with option `'valid'` to trim the replicated boundary pixels. If it is less than `4` or `8` it means that it is connected to at least one zero-valued pixel.